# Tamper data in Chrome question closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, off-topic

[Tamper data Chrome not working](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190755/tamper-data-chrome-not-working)

Could you please explain to me how a question about an extension, used for tampering data by many of security experts, is not related to a QA site on Information Security?

Comment: If you're asking how to tamper with data using the tool towards the ends of Information Security, that's on-topic (although asking "how to hack" isn't).  If you're asking how to install it, that's not on-topic; you should seek the appropriate support forum or method for that software.  Agreeing to close and shift to Meta.

Comment: @bonugoso Voting to migrate to Meta isn't supposed to be taken as an insult. If your question is about why your previous question was put on hold, it belongs in Meta. All the migration means is that you'll get proper answers there, since that's where the meta discussion is.

Comment: @bonugoso Welcome to Security.SE. Please remember to be nice - nasty and aggressive comments such as those will lead suspension.

Answer (score 8):

> Could you please explain me... how a question about an extension, used
>   for tampering data by many of security experts, is not related to a QA
>   site on Information Security.

If that question has to do about the security aspects of the extension, then it would be on-topic.  However, if the question is only about installing it - or why it doesn't function after installation - that's a simpler software support question, and not on-topic.

This is touched on by the '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' page when it says "Questions on setting up your home PC antivirus may be more appropriate at superuser.com..."  Software installation is a generic layer that doesn't touch on the Security aspects of the tool.

Also on that page it states that this site is "to discuss protecting assets from threats and vulnerabilities".  If you were asking how to use 'Tamper Data' when Penetration Testing, for example, that would be on-topic.

I don't know which issue from "Firefox not so long ago" you're referring to, but searching showed me [this page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1035527), which is a perfect example of why installation questions are better directed at the product forum - the answer there was more detailed and cogent than I'd expect from this site for such a question.

Good luck!